# Google Chrome on windows 7

Tags: google-chrome

Why are my webpages going black on Google Chrome? It is not doing it on IE 11. What is wrong with this question? It has proper grammar!

Comment: Go to chrome shortcut's properties and add ` --disable-gpu` to target. Open chrome advanced settings and deselect _Use hardware acceleration when available_. Does it now work properly?

Comment: It could be a myriad of things.  Did you at least try restarting the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I would just uninstall Chrome delete the Google folder under Program Files(x86) and reinstall.  Easiest way to know you got a pretty fresh install.

Comment: That won't solve it if all that's needed is a computer restart.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/1999-08-04